# How to remove a widget from the screen without rebuilding the whole page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets say i have a button and a container , and i want the container to disappear when i press the button.
Without rebuilding a new page, is this possible ? or is rebuilding the whole page is better?.

Comment: You can use state management libraries like Provider if you don't want to rebuild page completely. It will rebuild only components listening to it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do it without `setState` but rebuilding the entire view might not be necessary.

The scope of `setState` is the current widget so if you encapsulate just the controls involved in this operation in a separated widget, only this tree will be recreated and not the entire view.